# Multiple request sent by browser for audio tag

Tags: angular, html5-audio, src

I have an audio tag where the url is parsed and returned by a function.

```
<audio class="fr-draggable" controls autoplay [src]="extractAudioUrl(message)" style="width:100%"></audio>
```

But what happens is, multiple requests are sent by the browser back to back.

You can see the broswer requests below.

[image]

How can I get rid of this ?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple requests are sending because you are calling a function inside your `[src]` that's why this is happening

If you assign a url directly or by using a variable then issue is not occur 
And if you still want to call the function inside your `[src]` you need to change your `ChangeDetectionStrategy`. here is the
[ChangeDetectionStrategy Doc Link](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy)

Comment: I have tried changing the change detection strategy to onpush. still the same result. Any idea ?

Comment: If you disable the `changeDetectionStrategy` then there is also change that your two way binding is not working as expected. So what is suggest you is that for creating a URL you can create a custom `pipe` for that.